# Artifactory maven repository disabled?

Tags: maven, artifactory

Why maven repository are disabled?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have installed [Artifactory-cpp-ce](https://bintray.com/jfrog/product/JFrog-Artifactory-Cpp-CE/view#) which is available for the Conan community and Maven isn't available. If you want to use the Maven repositories in community type you can go with [Artifactory-oss](https://bintray.com/jfrog/product/JFrog-Artifactory-Oss/view) or you can licensed [Artifactory-pro](https://bintray.com/jfrog/product/JFrog-Artifactory-Pro/view). Under the Artifactory-cpp-ce, you will get access to Conan and generic repositories, under the Artifactory-oss, you will get access to Maven, Gradle, Ivy, SBT and generic repositories and under Artifactory-pro, all the repositories are accessible but Artifactory-pro is a licensed product.

Comment: Also, you can use the JFrog Artifactory free tier, refer this link https://jfrog.com/pricing/ for more information